# Simple Injector - Register Service with one custom Parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I try to register a communication service with a custom parameter "server". But i want automatic resolve the ILogger dependency and not set this dependency twice.

Whats the best way to do this?

**SimpleInjector Register**

```
var diContainer = new Container();
diContainer.Register<ILogger, DefaultLogger>();
//Good
diContainer.Register<ICommunicationService>(
    () => new CommunicationService("server1"), 
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
//Bad
diContainer.Register<ICommunicationService>(
    () => new CommunicationService(new DefaultLogger(), "server1"),
    Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

**CommunicationService Class**

```
public class CommunicationService : ICommunicationService
{
    public CommunicationService(ILogger logger, string server)
    {
    }
}
```

**Update 2017-11-27**

@Steven I want run two instances of `CommunicationService` with different configuration. In my example server1 and server2.

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<ILogger, DefaultLogger>();
container.RegisterSingleton(new CommunicationServiceConfig { Server = "server1" });
container.RegisterSingleton(new CommunicationServiceConfig { Server = "server2" });

diContainer.Register<ICommunicationService, CommunicationService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
diContainer.Register<ICommunicationService, CommunicationService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Comment: It does seem strange why `SimpleInjector` makes such heavy weather of a common case like this. Seemingly there was talk of adding a Ninject-like [WithConstructorParameter](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/246) but this was then dropped.

Comment: @StuartLC: Not really dropped, but simply not yet implemented :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Injection of primitive types is always an area of trouble for DI Containers, since primitive types such as `string` `int` and `bool` cause ambiguity.

The simplest solution therefore is to wrap this `string` configuration value into its own configuration class, for instance:

```
public class CommunicationServiceConfig
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
}
```

And let `CommunicationService` depend on on `CommunicationServiceConfig` rather than `string`:

```
public class CommunicationService : ICommunicationService
{
    public CommunicationService(ILogger logger, CommunicationServiceConfig config)
    {
    }
}
```

With this change, the Composition Root becomes:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<ILogger, DefaultLogger>();
container.RegisterSingleton(new CommunicationServiceConfig { Server = "server1" });

diContainer.Register<ICommunicationService, CommunicationService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, what i have to do, if i want to start two instances of ICommunicationService? I think this is not possible with your example code...

Comment: You mean each communication service with a different `server` value?

Comment: Yes with different `server` values.

Comment: @live2: Please update your question to show what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but it seems you can capture the container itself to resolve dependencies which have already been registered, in the actual bootstrapping phase itself, which can then be passed to the factory function registration, i.e.:

```
    diContainer.Register<ICommunicationService>(
        () => new CommunicationService(
         diContainer.GetInstance<ILogger>(), "server1"), Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Thus allowing a blend of hard coded values, e.g. for Config, Connection strings etc, plus the other resolved dependencies, although this will result in a lot of maintenance pain if constructor signatures are changed.

One thing to note is that SimpleInjector freezes registration once the first resolution has been made, so for example, the following isn't possible:

```
var sharedLogger = diContainer.GetInstance<ILogger>();

diContainer.Register<ICommunicationService>(
        () => new CommunicationService(sharedLogger, "server1"), Lifestyle.Singleton);
// Other registrations with `sharedLogger`
```

> System.InvalidOperationException : The container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance

i.e. you'll need to ensure your factory methods stay lazy.

Comment: The capturing of the container is similar to what you would do with containers as Autofac, where the container is passed along with the predicates you register, i.e. `c => c.Resolve<Something>()`. But true, it is not ideal, because it blinds the container in doing proper verification on the application's object graphs.

Comment: Singleton Lifestyle is just straight from [the book](https://manning.com/seemann/).

Comment: My bad - in fact I was thinking of Lifetime myself. If Mark Seemann says Lifestyle, lifestyle it is :) Great work on SimpleInjector btw - it's consistently top of the performance charts on the major .Net IOC's. Which reminds me, we need to reconsider our use of Ninject ASAP.

Comment: No, we sure don't want to argue with Mark on this :) About choice of container, if Ninject works well, why switch? There might however be [some compelling reasons](https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics) to switch to Simple Injector though, but as always make sure it fits the applications you are building.